# how to enable npm for all users

Tags: node.js, npm

On my server I have npm installed for root user; but with ssh users npm is not accessible:

```
-bash: npm: command not found
```

how can I enable the use of npm for all users?

Comment: type `which npm` and let me know what it says. if it's not in /usr/local that's why no user can access it

Comment: Right; since I use nvm it's in /root/.nvm/v0.10.31/bin/npm; but the fact is that also using sudo /root/.nvm/v0.10.31/bin/npm install I get a EACCESS error

Comment: Which linux distribution are you using?